# Ubuntu 21.04 on Dell Latidude E6530 : HDMI out only for a short while during boot

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, 21.04

Regardless of my Nvidia card is in performance mode or on-demand mode (PRIME profiles) - the HDMI does not work - except during boot, and until the login screen.(Login display makes it disappear)

FWIW: this laptop and HDMI worked fine with Ubuntu 20.10 - HDMI was detected on plugin.
I am using nvidia-driver-390
ubuntu/gnome makes no difference.
I am unable to select "ubuntu on xorg" when using nvidia Drivers (and intel does apparently not support the HDMI out)

Comment: Is it 21.10 or 21.04?

Comment: Sorry, my bad: 21.04